# Python and virtualbox vs virtualbox-6.1

Tags: virtualbox

What's the difference between `virtualbox` and `virtualbox-6.1`?

If you added the **virtualbox PPA** to your system (via /etc/apt/sources.list), you will find that you now have multiple versions of virtualbox available to install.

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal non-free contrib

wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

As viewed in `Synaptic Package Manager`, you'll see at least three different versions.

[image]

What's the difference, and which one should I install?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other than the slight version number differences, the big difference is what version of `python` it requires.

Most current installations of Ubuntu have both `python2` and `python3` installed. `Python2` is depreciated.

## **virtualbox-6.1**

- Uses python2.
- Installs `python-is-python2`, and makes `python2` the system default.

`python-is-python2`:

> [image]

## **virtualbox**

- Uses python3.
- Replaces `python-is-python2` with `python-is-python3`, and makes `python3` the system default.

`python-is-python3`:

> [image]

Here, I'm installing the slightly older `virtualbox` and you can see what happens with the `python-is-python*` files.

> [image]

So which `virtualbox` to install comes down to which version(s) of `python` that you have installed, and if you have both installed, which one you want as system default.

Answer (score 0):

Version 6.1 was a bit update.

> The following major new features were added:
>
> - Implemented support for importing a virtual machine from Oracle Cloud Infrastructure
> - Extended support for exporting a virtual machine to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure, allowing the creation of multiple virtual machines
>   without re-uploading. Also added option to export a VM to the cloud
>   using the more efficient variant "paravirtialized", and to specify
>   free-form tags for cloud images
> - Virtualization core: Support for nested hardware-virtualization on Intel CPUs (starting with 5th generation Core i, codename
>   Broadwell), so far tested only with guest running VirtualBox
> - Graphics: New style 3D support (with VBoxSVGA and VMSVGA) remains, old style 3D support (with VBoxVGA) has been completely
>   removed
> - Shared Clipboard: Implemented experimental support for file transfers (Windows hosts/guests only at the moment). Needs to be
>   enabled via VBoxManage (disabled by default).

For more details view the changelog https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog