# Cannot install virtualbox 6.1 on Ubuntu 20.04. The following packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, xorg, dependencies

As tittle said, I tried to search for solutions but I can't find anything. Can you suggest another software beside virtualbox? Thank you.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox-6.0 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.12.2) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Your subject title says VB6.1, but you're installing 6.0. You should be installing `virtualbox` or `virtualbox-6.1`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295530/python-and-virtualbox-vs-virtualbox-6-1

Comment: @heynnema I tried to install both, but I can't get it. But think you for your link with a lot of infomations. I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I follow a guide
I just change the server to download package and it works like a charm.

> Press simultaneously Alt and F2 on your computer, type in
> `software-properties-gtk`
> and press Enter.
> In the Ubuntu Software tab, make sure that all the repositories (main, universe, restricted, multiverse) are enabled.
> Click the list of servers where it says Download from, and choose
> Click Select Best Server.
> Press Alt, Ctrl and T simultaneously to open a Terminal, and type in
>
> `sudo apt update`
>
> then press Once it’s done running, try
> installing the software again.

Comment: You also need to do `sudo apt upgrade` or `Software Updater` to make sure that your system is current.